# Not able to access test db from rake tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm unable to execute `bundle exec rake` because for some reason I can't connect to my database, the error is more than obvious :

```
rake aborted!
Java::JavaSql::SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

You're seeing Java etc. because I'm using jRuby. So my next move was to start a rails console in test mode which I did with `rails console test`. Worked just fine, I tried to create a new object just in case and I was able to do it with no issues.

So why is my `bundle exec rake` failing to connect to the db? And what can I do  to fix this? The test db configuration is fine because I can use the test rails console right?

Have no idea what to try next, any hints/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Does `rails console test` show `Loading test environment (Rails 4.2.0)` on starting up with the appropriate version of rails? It might be that it is still loading up development environment for som e reason.

Comment: yes it says `Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.17)`, what can I do about it?

Comment: OK; confirms that the console is indeed connecting to test database. Could you reverify that you can access database objects from the console with `<Model>.first` for some model in your app?

Comment: I use database cleaner so I have no data in my test db. However I can do `Model.first` and I can even do `Model.create` and `Model.last.delete` which would indicated that I connect to test db

Comment: Hmmm, can't think of anything else that could be wrong. Some random suggestions: 1. Try upgrading rails version to 3.2.18 or higher; if there was some specific issue related to 3.2.17 that would have been fixed by now. 2. Delete `config/database.yml` altogether, and create it afresh and try again.

Comment: Did you figure this out?